# How to find similiarity between two row data

Tags: correlation, python, similarities

I try to remove one of almost duplicated data from data set programmatically. My data set is logically like the table below.As you see there is two rows in data set and a human can understand easily that this two data is related and probably added by same person.

[image]

My solution to this problem is using Levenshtein two compare fields(name,address,telephone number) separately and find their similarity ratio. Then I calculate average ratio as 0.77873. This similarity results seems to low. My python code is like

```
from Levenshtein import ratio
name     =  ratio("Game of ThOnes Books for selling","Selling Game of Thrones books")
address  =  ratio("George Washington street","George Washington st.")
phone    =  ratio("555-55-55","0(555)-55-55")

total_ratio = name+address+phone
print total_ratio/3 #Average ratio
```

My question is what is the best way two compare row data? Which algorithms or methodologies is require for doing this?

Comment: Take a look at [OpenRefine](http://openrefine.org/). If the budget allows, also consider [Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) or similar services.

Comment: Actually i want algorithmic solution. We can compare two string easily find similarity percentage. However comparing two rows is more cumbersome. As a human we can perceive these two data are related. I want to solve same logic works for computer

Comment: Possibly this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/find-the-similarity-percent-between-two-strings

Comment: @user1367204 actually i can calculate similarity separately as you see in my code. I am not just comparing name, address and phone seperately. These data are interrelated.